# How to group lines by one column?

Tags: python

I want to write a function tha for input like this

```
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,           SUTD_GLAB,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2c,            SUTD_BOT,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2b,        SUTD_Student,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2a,          SUTD_Staff,   72

  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:29,           SUTD_ILP2,   71

  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:eb,        SUTD_Student,   57

  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:ea,          SUTD_Staff,   57
```

the output will give me two lists or files grouped by the first column, which means if the number in the fist column is the same, it will group as a list. The result should be like this:

List one:

```
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,           SUTD_GLAB,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2c,            SUTD_BOT,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2b,        SUTD_Student,   72

  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2a,          SUTD_Staff,   72
```

List two:

```
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:29,           SUTD_ILP2,   71

  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:eb,        SUTD_Student,   57

  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:ea,          SUTD_Staff,   57
```

I don't know which method I should use.

Comment: Does the first columns only contain  `1405684432` or `1405684433` or are other values possible?

Comment: @Tichodroma Got other values:)

Comment: where is the input coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I use a android app collect the data, these are time and wifi infomation:)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `itertools.groupby()`. (Assuming the input is sorted by that column.)

Example:

```
import itertools

data = """\
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,           SUTD_GLAB,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2c,            SUTD_BOT,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2b,        SUTD_Student,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2a,          SUTD_Staff,   72
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:29,           SUTD_ILP2,   71
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:eb,        SUTD_Student,   57
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:ea,          SUTD_Staff,   57
"""

data = data.splitlines()
keyfunc = lambda x: x.split(',')[0]
#data.sort(key=keyfunc) # if input is not sorted by first column

for k,l in itertools.groupby(data, key=keyfunc):
    print "group:", k
    for x in l:
        print x
```

Output:

```
group:   1405684432
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,           SUTD_GLAB,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2c,            SUTD_BOT,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2b,        SUTD_Student,   72
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2a,          SUTD_Staff,   72
group:   1405684433
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:29,           SUTD_ILP2,   71
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:eb,        SUTD_Student,   57
  1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:ea,          SUTD_Staff,   57
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to use a dictionary to keep track of the first column. A solution would be to use something like:

```
def split_on_first_column(data):
    result = dict()
    for line in data:
        l = line.split(',')
        if not l[0] in result:
            result[l[0]] = [line]
        else:
            result[l[0]].append(line)

    return result.values()
```

Which in python 2 gives you a list of lists in this case and an iterator over lists in python 3.

Note that the lines are stored as complete strings and not split further into lists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the input as a CSV file
2. Use the first column as the key for a dictionary
3. Ouput the dictionary

Python code:

```
import csv

groups = {}

with open("data.csv") as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 0:
            col1 = row[0].strip()
            group = groups.get(col1, [])
            group.append(row)
            groups[col1] = group

for key in groups:
    print("=== {0} ===".format(key))
    print("\n".join(",".join(row) for row in groups[key]))
```

Output:

```
=== 1405684433 ===
1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:29,           SUTD_ILP2,   71
1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:eb,        SUTD_Student,   57
1405684433,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:ea,          SUTD_Staff,   57
=== 1405684432 ===
1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,           SUTD_GLAB,   72
1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2c,            SUTD_BOT,   72
1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2b,        SUTD_Student,   72
1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2a,          SUTD_Staff,   72
```